How do I call a javascript function from Google Chrome Dev console?
When I change the theme of Home Assistant (by clicking radio button at user's profile, demo), it calls fireEvent, if I read the source correctly.
I would like to call it from the browser's console, but if I do
fireEvent(this, "settheme", { dark: true });

I get
VM1775:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: fireEvent is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1

How can I access this function? Later I will call this function from the TamperMonkey script.
The following code is used in JS files:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/home-assistant/frontend/20240906.0/src/common/dom/fire_event.ts:
declare global {
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  interface HASSDomEvents {}
}

export type ValidHassDomEvent = keyof HASSDomEvents;
  ...

export const fireEvent = <HassEvent extends ValidHassDomEvent>(
  ...

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/home-assistant/frontend/20240906.0/src/panels/profile/ha-pick-theme-row.ts:
import { fireEvent } from "../../common/dom/fire_event";

The Dev tools shows also the following info:


This question is similar to: Accessing Variables from Greasemonkey to Page & vice versa. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@double-beep, thanks. The question answers how to access variable from the Greasemonkey script, I would like to understand how it works with Dev Console. I tried to apply the same logic to my case, but variables are not available in Console by that way.

The function should exist within in the 'global' scope, in a browser that's window. So temporarily adding fireEvent to the window scope within the [ha-pick-theme-row.ts I suppose] script should do the trick.
import { fireEvent } from "../../common/dom/fire_event";
window.fireEvent = fireEvent;

After the page is loaded, fireEvent or window.fireEvent should be available in the developer console.

Thanks, but import doesn't work there -
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

I suppose you mean within the developer console? See edits ...

Ok, got your idea now. But I am looking for a way to do it without 3rd party scripts modification. If is it impossible within the developer console, could it be done from tampermonkey?

In a far and forgotten past I inicdentally used tampermonkey, but I really can't tell if it can be used for that - allthough my bet would be that it couldn't :/

The GitHub link you've provided points to a TypeScript file. TypeScript cant run in browsers so you'll need to transpile it to JavaScript first. You'll also need to remove the "export" declaration for the fireEvent function; the "import" and "export" keywords can only be used in modules.
Your transpiled code:
    // Polymer legacy event helpers used courtesy of the Polymer project.
    //
    // Copyright (c) 2017 The Polymer Authors. All rights reserved.
    //
    // Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
    // modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are
    // met:
    //
    //    * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
    // notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
    //    * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above
    // copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer
    // in the documentation and/or other materials provided with the
    // distribution.
    //    * Neither the name of Google Inc. nor the names of its
    // contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived from
    // this software without specific prior written permission.
    //
    // THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
    // "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
    // LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
    // A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT
    // OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
    // SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
    // LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
    // DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
    // THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
    // (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
    // OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.

    // Define your function:
    function fireEvent(node, type, detail, options) {
        options = options || {};
        detail = detail === null || detail === undefined ? {} : detail;
        const event = new Event(type, {
            bubbles: options.bubbles === undefined ? true : options.bubbles,
            cancelable: Boolean(options.cancelable),
            composed: options.composed === undefined ? true : 
            options.composed,
        });
        event.detail = detail;
        node.dispatchEvent(event);
        return event;
    };

    // Call your function:
    fireEvent(this, "settheme", { True });

You can then save the above into your browsers developer tools, under Sources > Snippets > New snippet. (Dev Tools Snippets).

Thanks. It also requires the node. When radiobutton is selected, then ha-pick-theme-row is passed. If I just run the snippet, then window (?) is used. And the code doesn't work. Any idea how to pass the node?

Didnt spot this - because it's an arrow function, this binds to the global window object. See updated answer with the revised syntax.

Also, if you're just after triggering the theme change, you can simulate a click event on the radio button.

Thank you. It doesn't work just with function declaration - EvalError: Identifier 'fireEvent' cannot be declared with 'var' in current evaluation scope, consider trying 'let' instead and when I modify it to const fireEvent = (node, type, detail, options) => { it returns TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dispatchEvent').

I would like to trigger the theme change, but it should work from any page for me, so I can not just click the button.
